# WordPress Wesbsite Browser Tab Text Problem

Tags: wordpress

I have posted a Post and on some of the post the browser tab text is showing this text instead of post title "Internal Use Only". You can also check screenshot. [image]

Any One here help me to fix that. I want to show Post title here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wordpress seo plugin named "The SEO Framework By Sybre Waaijer", Your post title is controlled by this plugin.

If you edit the post, you may see a section like the image below somewhere below the post text editor.

[image]

Change the "Custom Post Title"  as your need. Let me know if this solved your problem or not.

Comment: Hi First the title was "25 INCREDIBLE Places to Visit in Canada [[date] • Insider Guide!]" then i just remove the first "25" and new title is "INCREDIBLE Places to Visit in Canada [[date] • Insider Guide!]" then its fixed... but i need 25 also... what should be the issue.

Comment: So you are saying if the post title starts with a number, it does not work properly ? Must be an weird issue. Have you tried contacting the plugin developer ?

Comment: Not for all.
One of the post starting with number and this post title is perfectly fine. but its not working for some of the posts.